# replace div text with another div in div jquery onload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

```
<div class="main">
<div class="first">A text</div>
<div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="first">C text</div>
<div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```

I want to change B text with A text and D text with C text with jquery. I added this script:

```
$('.second').html($('.first').html());
```

but it change A text in both main div

Comment: So you will have to loop over the main elements and select them

Comment: Your code is looking for any first result for `.first`. What you should be doing is look for `element.parent().find('.first')` but you'll have to loop through the `.second` matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is when you use text() it will return the first item in the collection. It has no clue you want to grab it for other elements. So you need to code it to deal with the relationships.

You will have to loop over each group and select each one in the group.

```js
$(".main").each( function () {
  var elem = $(this)
  var text = elem.find(".second").text()
  elem.find(".first").text(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">A text</div>
<div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="first">C text</div>
<div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```

Other option is to select all the elements and loop over

```js
var firsts = $(".first")
var seconds = $(".second")

firsts.each( function (index) {
  $(this).text(seconds.eq(index).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">A text</div>
<div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="first">C text</div>
<div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```

and without each

```js
var firsts = $(".first")
var seconds = $(".second")

firsts.text( function (index) {
  return seconds.eq(index).text()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">A text</div>
<div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="first">C text</div>
<div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because your code selects all `.first` elements.

To fix the problem you can select the second `div` in each `.main` block and provide a function to `text()` which returns the text of the previous sibling. Try this:

```js
$('.main > div:nth-child(2)').text(function() {
  return $(this).prev().text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">A text</div>
  <div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="first">C text</div>
  <div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```

Note that the `.first` and `.second` classes are no longer necessary with this approach

Comment: Thank you Rory,its working, can you please do it without selector.

Comment: So in this case which text should be overwritten? I'd suggest updating the question with a more accurate example of the HTML

Comment: can you do it with only class name

Comment: Probably, but you haven't shown what the class names are for the other divs. @epascarello's answer shows solutions which may work for that case. You should note that the better approach, IMO, would be to do it using ordinal position in the container, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try loop over the `.main`, get the `.first` and `.second` element and swap the values.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

     $.each( $('.main'), function() {
   var $first  = $(this).find('.first');
   var firstHTML = $($first).html();
        var $second = $(this).find('.second');
   
        $($second).html(firstHTML);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="first">A text</div>
<div class="second">B text</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="first">C text</div>
<div class="second">D text</div>
</div>
```